# SQL how to sort text with numbers alphabetically, then numerically

Tags: sql, sql-server, numeric

I have a table that has alphanumeric values. I'd like to order them alphabetically then numerically. I'm editing the question for more help... I only need the numbers at the end of the string to be sorted numerically...

example I'd like this

```
ControlName (column)
--------------------
VALVE 1
MAIN VALVE
VALVE 10
BOILER 2
VALVE 17
BOILER 1
VALVE 19
VALVE 2
```

To be sorted as this

```
ControlName (column)
----------------
BOILER 1
BOILER 2
MAIN VALVE
VALVE 1
VALVE 2
VALVE 10
VALVE 17
VALVE 19
```

Whats a (light) query that can get this done?

Comment: So when you have 2 sections of numbers you don't care about the first section of numbers? It is always whatever is the last section of numbers? So Zone 10 sorts above Zone 2 because of the last numbers in the string? Is that one columns of data or two? Can you turn this into insert statements so we know what we are working with?

Comment: I guess so. Is there a way to sort that numerically as well? I would rather that

Comment: @SeanLange I updated my question

Comment: But please help us with the details of your sample data. I don't know if this is one column or two. And if it is two what is what column??

Comment: @Hogan they changed the desired output when I asked for clarity but didn't update the sample data to match.

Comment: @Hogan I apologize, the values do not change. that was a typo

Comment: @goldie -- there is no "light" query that can do this unless the string and numeric values are in different columns.  If they aren't you are going to have to parse the data before you sort it.

Comment: is it only 1 or two pairs of string numeric?  also what is the logic for sorting the non-number 2nd value (`VALVE`)

Comment: It is one long string, You can ignore the numbers in the middle, but I would like it sorted alphabetically V (valve) comes before Z (zone) but within the Valves I would like Valve 2 to come before Valve 10.... and so on

Comment: so you only care about the starting pair?

Comment: I updated my question, thank you

Comment: Ugh the problem scope keeps changing.

Comment: @SeanLange sorry! if you can answer my original question that would be even more awesome! I'm starting to think that may be too hard, at a certain point its too bad if the user decides to name their controls with too many numbers ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the problem sits right now we want to sort by the last set of numbers if there are more than 1 set of number sections in the string. This code will do that. If there is only one set of numbers or even no numbers this works.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ControlName varchar(50)
)

insert @Something values
('VALVE 1')
, ('MAIN VALVE')
, ('VALVE 10')
, ('BOILER 2')
, ('VALVE 17')
, ('BOILER 1')
, ('VALVE 19')
, ('VALVE 2')

select *
from @Something
order by left(ControlName, LEN(ControlName) - patindex('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(ControlName)) + 1) --this gets the "prefix" or characters before the last set of numbers
    , convert(int, right(ControlName, patindex('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(ControlName)) - 1)) --this gets the last set of numbers
```

Comment: Thank you! and its really fast

Comment: The performance might get pretty ugly on larger sets. But should be pretty quick on smaller datasets. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that adds up to two zeros before numbers that come at the end of text. For example Boiler 1 will become Boiler 001 and Boiler 12 would become Boiler 012.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[sortTextWithNum](@text nvarchar(max))
returns nvarchar(max) as 
begin
    declare @reverse nvarchar(max) = reverse(@text)
    declare @numIndex int = patindex('%[^0-9]%', @reverse)
    return iif(@numIndex=1, @text, substring(@text, 0, len(@text)-@numIndex+2) + format(cast(reverse(left(@reverse, @numIndex-1)) as int),'D3'))
end
```

You can use it like this:

```
select ControlName from [YourTable] order by dbo.sortTextWithNum(ControlName)
```

Comment: this won't work, he has some columns with two different sets of numerics that need to be sorted on and you are picking the last ones which in his example above does not work.

Comment: apparently the problem got simpler so this is the best answer +1

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler statement of the ordering is:

```
select *
from @something s
order by left(ControlName, patindex('%[0-9]%', ControlName + '0') - 1),
         len(ControlName),
         ControlName
```

The order by keys do the following:

- Order by everything before the first number.
- Order by the length of the control name, so shorter numbers (`1`) are before larger numbers (`100`).
- Order by the name, so the numbers are in order.

Comment: I think this could be slower than @MP 's answer.  He is only doing starts with in the  the pattern matching so it should be faster assuming a string reverse is basically free.

Comment: @Hogan . . . You think that two calls to `patindex()` and `reverse()`, along with other calls is going to be slower than this?  That is, `patindex()` + `reverse()` + `right()` <  `len()` (these are the remaining operations).  I don't think so.  There might be some benefit to slightly shorter ordering keys, but it is unclear how much of a benefit that is.  But, in actual fact, the actual sorting is probably what is going to dominate the performance.

Comment: yeah that is true, non-indexed sorting is very slow.